# How to hide the search field name menu bar in Kibana Discover

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, dashboard

Can anyone please explain to me how to hide or remove the search field name menu bar in Kibana Discover when seeing the logs.
For more details, please see the image that I attached above. In that case, I need to hide/remove the highlighted part.

[Kibana screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nx7ov.png)

[Highlighted Kibana screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymQ5j.png)

I tried it with a small button to the right of the sidebar which allows me to hide.

But I followed those steps and share the iframe URL to someone, it again showed the menu bar.